# Golang what is the optimize way to append and remove character

Tags: string, go

In go, we have the [`strings.Builder`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder) to append characters which is better than using `s = s + string(character)`, but how about is there an optimal way to remove the last character instead of `s = s[:len(s)-sizeOfLastCharacter]`?

Comment: Note that using slicing like that will cause problems when the string contains characters which take up more than 1 byte. https://play.golang.org/p/_017wGYNfa4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slicing is a very efficient operation, as detailed in [slice internals](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro):

> Slicing does not copy the slice's data. It creates a new slice value that points to the original array. This makes slice operations as efficient as manipulating array indices.

Effectively, removing the last element of a slice means creating a new slice descriptor pointing to the same array but with a smaller length. Short of direct access to the internals of a slice, you won't find a more efficient solution.

Comment: What if I have a stringsBuilder, then I want to remove its last character, in this case, I can't use slicing in stringsBuilder so how should I approach?

Comment: You can't, a builder is used to append to efficiently, you cannot truncate the underlying byte slice. The best you can do is truncate the output of `b.String()` but it won't change the builder.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`utf8.DecodeLastRuneInString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#DecodeLastRuneInString) to find out how many bytes the last rune "occupies", and slice the original string based on that. Slicing a `string` results in a `string` value that shares the backing array with the original, so the `string` content is not copied, just a new string header is created which is just 2 integer values (see [`reflect.StringHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StringHeader)).

For example:

```
s := "Hello, 世界"
r, size := utf8.DecodeLastRuneInString(s)
if r != utf8.RuneError {
    s = s[:len(s)-size]
}
fmt.Println(s)
```

Outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/q7AxL22-mBL)):

```
Hello, 世
```